# UICollectionView really slow when scrolling

Tags: parse-platform, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So, I've thrown together some code that will download images and display them on the custom UICollectionViewCell that I've created, but scrolling is terribly slow. Should the code that is in the function below be moved to a NSObject class that can do the downloading for me somehow? I'm super lost on what to do to speed things up..

Thank you in advance! :)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as HomeCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()


    var post:PFObject = self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    var imageFile:PFFile = post.objectForKey("file") as PFFile
    var imageFileURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: imageFile.url)!
    var imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageFileURL)!

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) it will take care of the downloading/viewing async